# Import-Export script

Tags: scripting, 3dsmax, maxscript

Can you please help me with creating a script which imports and export list of files? Let's say i've got a list of .nif or .fbx model filepaths, i need the script to import and then export file and proceed next filepath in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to find the documentation on how to import/export files in maxscript here:
https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-624D3D05-B15D-4A97-9F15-DA35CDB0DDD2

You might also be interested in the documentation around 3dsmaxbatch.exe to run 3ds Max in "headless" mode for automation here:
https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-48A78515-C24B-4E46-AC5F-884FBCF40D59

You can also find documentation on how to implement different control flow statements in maxscript like loop and if statement here:
https://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-FF6342F0-31A0-40EE-A9BD-FC9120D1A463

Comment: sorry for late response, i'll check that out thanks, i'll come later with an update how did it go